# How to upload HTML file to an Azure Web App using Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Python application which creates a HTML file which I then want to upload to an Azure Web Application.

What is the best way to do this?

I originally started try to do it using FTP and then switched to pushing with GIT. None of these really felt right. How should I be doing this?

**UPDATE**

I have this 99% working. I'm using a Storage Account to host a static site (which feels like the right way to do this).

This is how I am uploading:

```
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(az_string)
        # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)

        print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)

        # Upload the created file
        with open('populated.html', "rb") as data:
            blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

The only problem that I have now, is that the file is downloading instead of opening in the browser. I think I need to set the content type somewhere.

**Update 2**
Working now, I added:

```
my_content_settings = ContentSettings(content_type='text/html')

test = blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True, content_settings=my_content_settings)
```

Cheers,

Mick

Comment: Hi, Mick. Is your Azure Web App for Windows? And is it host a static website which HTML files generated from your Python application? If it's a static website, do you mind to switch to Azure Blob Storage Gen 2 to host it with its feature `Static website`?

Comment: Both will do the job. What's the problem with them? What did not *feel* (?) right?

Comment: @PeterPan It is a static website. Yes the Python generates the HTML for the site. It basically scrapes a few sites for weather data, then combines it to form a small static site. Don't mind how it is hosted. Just want to do this the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is up to you.

Generally, there are two ways to upload a HTML file to Azure Web App for Windows, as below.

1. Following the Kudu wiki page [Accessing files via ftp](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-files-via-ftp) to upload a file via FTP.
2. Following the sections `VFS`, `Zip` and `Zip Deployment` of Kudu wiki page [REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API) to call the related `PUT` REST API to upload a file via HTTP client.

However, based on my understanding for your scenario, the two ways above are not simple. So I recommanded to use the feature [`Static website`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) of Azure Blob Storage Gen 2 to host your static HTML file generated by your Python application and to upload files via Azure Storage SDK for Python. I think it's simple enough to you, even you can bind a custom domain to the default host name of static website of Azure Blob Storage via DNS CNAME.

The steps are below.

1. Refer to the offical document [`Host a static website in Azure Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-how-to?tabs=azure-portal) to create an account of Azure Blob Storage Gen 2 and enable the feature `Static website`.
2. Refer to the other offical document [`Quickstart: Azure Blob storage client library v12 for Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) to write the code for uploading in your current Python application . The container default named `$web` is for hosting static website, you just need to upload the files to it, then access its primary endpoint as the figure from offical document below to see it.

   [image]

Comment: OK, I will give this a go. Thanks.